# get images from xml which contains path of images

Tags: android, xml

I have an XML file which contains the path of the images like the below code:

```
<Source>
  <ID>001</ID>
  <Name>News</Name>
  <Country>United States</Country>
  <FeedURL>
    http://abcd.xml
  </FeedURL>
  <Download>true</Download>
  <Image>
    http://creativityinlife.files.wordpress.com/2009/03/as_much_as_i_dream.jpg
  </Image>
</Source>
```

I want to retrieve and display the image. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your xml is very simple you can use DOM parser, Refer [Android XML Parsing Tutorial – Using DOMParser](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-%E2%80%93-using-domparser/) and take that url
Then load that url using [Load Image from server using thread](http://myandroidnote.blogspot.com/2011/03/load-image-from-server-using-thread.html)

Comment: i loaded both the xml file and image from url seperately, but how to load the image from xml id. Still am not clear in this.